# received unregistered task of type

Tags: celery, celery-task

I am trying to run tasks which are in the memory .
registerd tasks on worker

```
[2012-09-13 11:10:18,928: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] [u'B.run', u'M1.run', u'M11.run', u'M22.run', u'M23.run', u'M24.run', u'M25.run', u'M26.run', u'M4.run', u'celery.backend_cleanup', u'celery.chain', u'celery.chord', u'celery.chord_unlock', u'celery.chunks', u'celery.group', u'celery.map', u'celery.starmap', u'impmod.run', u'initializerNew.run']
```

but it still gives errors:

```
[2012-09-13 11:19:59,848: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'M24.run'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'retries': 0, 'task': 'M24.run', 'eta': None, 'args': [{'cnt': '3', 'ids': '0001-0004,0002-0004', 'NagID': 2, 'wgt': '3', 'ModID': 'M24', 'ProfileModuleID': 64, 'mhs': '1'}, 0], 'expires': None, 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'id': 'ddf5f520-803b-4dc9-ad3b-a931d90950a6', 'utc': True} (394b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.0.4-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 410, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body, message.ack_log_error)
KeyError: 'M24.run'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach command which starts Celery? Looks like this application have different sys.path, that's why celery app couldn't import 'M24.run' task.

Also you should remember that Celery requires setting module names where your tasks are localted.

Something similar to

```
CELERY_INCLUDE = [
    'M24',
]
```